# Syntax Error : Google Spread Sheet script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I tried to create a function for google spread sheet. However Appscipt editor doesn't compile my function and throws error, "Error Message: TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.getUi(...).createMenu(...).addItem(...).addItem(...).addSeperator is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is just a typo `addSeperator` to `addSeparator`:

###### `Code.gs`

```js
const addToUI = () => {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().
  createMenu('New Menu')
  .addItem('test1', 'test')
  .addItem('test2','test')
  .addSeparator().addToUi()
}

const test = () => console.log("ECO")
```

You can follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) for more reference.

Comment: I re-wrote the complete line of code again with required indexing, somehow it worked.